# My success function of ajax call not working properly but if I open console window in works fine with same code

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to redirect my to 'window.location.href = '/QuestionnaireManagement/Questionnaire/NewQuestionnaire';' on success i also tried top.location and location.replace but the same problem occurs I added debuggers in code and when I open the console window and then hit the success function is works fine but if I close the console window it doesn't work. Even no errors is showing in console.

```
function Signin() {
    try{        
        var frmdata = $('form').serialize();
        var UserName = $('#Name').val();
        var LoginPassword = $('#LoginPassword').val();
        if (UserName == '' || LoginPassword == '')
        {
            alert("Username and password is required.");
            return false;
        }
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Checkuser", "User")",
            type: "Post",
            data: frmdata,//{ UserName, LoginPassword },                      
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                if (response.data == 1)
                {
                    alert("success");
                    window.location.href = '/QuestionnaireManagement/Questionnaire/NewQuestionnaire';
                }
                else {
                    alert("Username or password is incorrect. Please check and try again.");
                    var iUrl = "@Url.Action("Login", "User")";
                    window.location.href = iUrl;                    
                }                
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put alert and see the errors and details

Comment: I putted it same problem when the console window open alert show otherwise it also not showing.

Comment: so it means its not going till the alert and failing before. you can use try catch

Comment: I added try catch but no error is showing in console

Comment: i am adding my updated code in question.